# Creating figures for publication - artefacts in export

Tags: matlab, pdf, latex, figure, eps

Now I am already trying for hours to get a satisfying vectorized output from a 3D matlab plot. I illustrated the artefacts of the resulting pdf exports in the following image (created with export_fig -> -r2000). I know that this problem is somehow related to the pdf viewer, but is there no solution to get a compatible output for all viewers?

In addition I have tried libs like plot2svg and matlab2tikz, but they seem to have problems with some of my surface plots resulting in completely different problems.

If there are no other ways to create vectorized outputs of the figures, do you have any tips for high quality bitmap figures (especially regarding to the font blurring)?

[image: Matlab 3D artefacts]

Comment: Could you add a (short) graph creation code sample?

Comment: For me the preferred method for preparing papers for publication is to use PostScript, and convert the resulting PS file to pdf. I have never had any problems with exporting matlab plots to eps, just "save as" the figure, and choose eps as the file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, exporting matlab figures results with less than satisfying results.
Personally, I prefer to export the data to other programs and create the plots there.
Excel does pretty good job with many types of figures. You may also try gnuplot.
I know this is not exactly the answer you are looking for but sometime instead of fighting Matlab, it is best to leave this jobs to better suited software.